# Checkbox table to select rows

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have just created a table with some values. I want to select all checkboxes with the first checkbox and uncheck them.
print "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";

```
my $script = qq{
\$('#id').change(function() {
var checkboxes = \$(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
if(\$(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
} else {
    checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
}
```

});
};

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

$q = new CGI;
print $q->start_html(
-title=>"Read a File",
-style  => {-src =>'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet'},
     -script => [
        {-src =>'js/jquery-1.9.1.js'}, 
        {-src =>'js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js'

        }, 
      ],   
);

my @aRows = ();

my $oCheckAll = $q->input({-type => 'checkbox', -name => 'sel_all', -id =>'id' }, 'Select All');

# Add header of table
push @aRows, (
   $q->Tr($q->th([$oCheckAll, 'Name', 'Surname', 'DB'])),   
);

# Add table rows
for(my $i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
   push @aRows, (
      $q->Tr($q->td([$q->input({-type => 'checkbox' -id => 'id'}), "EMR", "MB", $i]))
   );
}

print $q->style(".table th, td { width: 25%;}");

print $q->tabl
```

e({-class => 'table', -b

Comment: You've tagged this with `javascript` tag, where's the JS code?

Comment: What language is this by the way :)

Comment: could u update the code i have edited please?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle example, your code is very confusing and it's not clear the language you are using. (wich one and where) Also, re-tag with the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function (){
    var thisCheck = $(this);
    if (thischeck.is(':checked')){
        thisCheck.parent().children('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: when i check the first checkbox no other check box is checked as i want. im using this \$('#id').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}); but even this doesnt help

Comment: can you create an example on js fiddle. I'll just update your code there.

Comment: just edited my code, take a look pelase . i also want the uncheck option

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a bug in this variant:

```
$('table tr td:first-child input').click(function(event){
  $(this).parent().parent().find("td input").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/7shEz/1/) link.

```
$('table tr td:first-child input').click(function(event){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("td input:not(:checked)").click();
  } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("td input:checked").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: i doesn't work "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input "

Comment: @Armida in what browser? I have a good work in IE, Opera, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. You really watched this link? [http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/7shEz/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/7shEz/1/)